# How to detect azide group on a primer?

Tags: biochemistry

I bought azide-labeled primer for click chemistry, but it didn't work. So I want to prove the existence of azide group. How could I achieve this? I found a method to add `PPh3` to Kaiser test reagents, but the concentration of the primer is too low (the protocol needs the solution be higher than 0.1M) and I cannot see the reaction.

Comment: Does click reaction work with labeled nucleotide?

Comment: No. That's why I would suspect there's problem with azide group :(

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to check the IR spectrum.  If there's any azide in there the azide band should show up as a strong band at around 2150 cm<sup>-1</sup>.  The trouble is of course that this isn't quantitative, you can only prove the absence of azide, not how much is present.

The [Staudinger reaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staudinger_reaction) might be a viable option.  PPh<sub>3</sub> won't go up in aqueous solution, but [sulfonated PPh<sub>3</sub>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TPPTS) will.  One should be able to distinguish starting material and product by <sup>31</sup>P NMR.  With a known quantity of TPPTS you can even determine % azide in the starting material.